# Ant Build: "Failed to create task, Cause: name is undefined"

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, ibm-rad

I get this error when I try running an Ant Build:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type http://com.ibm.adapter:createProject
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```

I checked the Runtime JRE (Run in the same JRE as the workspace).
It seems like it can't find the right jar, so I added it (com.ibm.adapter.command) in the Ant Home Entries, but it doesn't work anyway.

Here is the script (even if there shouldn't be problems in this because in another computers worka, I think the problem is only about RAD configuration)

```
<project default="CreateRigaVariazioneSostituzione" name="/EssigIntegrazione/RigaVariazioneSostituzione.xml" xmlns:adapter="http://com.ibm.adapter">
    <property name="debug" value="true"/>
    <property name="projCpy2Java" value="EssigIntegrazione"/>

    <target name="CreateRigaVariazioneSostituzione">
        <adapter:createProject projectName="${projCpy2Java}" projectType="Java" sourceFolder="/src"/>

         ....
    </target>
</project>
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install J2C Connector from IBM Installation Manager